# Error registering Angular 1.5 component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I have the following Angular 1.5 component:

```
  (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('EmployeeInformation')
    .controller('EmployeeDetailCtrl', EmployeeDetailCtrl)
    .component('employeeDetail', EmployeeDetail);

    var EmployeeDetail = {
      templateUrl: '../views/components/employeeDetail.html',
      controller: 'EmployeeDetailCtrl as empdetail',
      bindings: {
        employee: '<'
      }
    };

    function EmployeeDetailCtrl() { }
  })();
```

Based on the examples on Angular's site, it seems correct to me.  However, when I include the file on my page, I get an error saying that it cannot register the component:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module EmployeeInformation due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
    at $CompileProvider.registerComponent [as component]
```

If I remove the reference to this component, the page loads fine.  Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I have a service in the same module composed similarly (that is wrapped in a function and without an empty array - see below) that works correctly:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('EmployeeInformation')
  .service('EmployeeService', EmployeeService);

  EmployeeService.$inject = ['$http'];

  function EmployeeService($http) {
    var apiPrefix = 'http://dvlemployees/api/employees';
    this.find = find;
    this.get = get;
    this.getOne = getOne;

    function find(queryObj) { }

    function get() { }

    function getOne(empNumber) { }
})();
```

EDIT2: Thanks to @Frondor, I figured out the true problem was that I was calling `angular.component` on the object before I had defined it.  Moving the `var EmployeeDetail` section to the top fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### JavaScript

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('EmployeeInformation', [])
.controller('EmployeeDetailCtrl', EmployeeDetailCtrl)
.component('employeeDetail', {
  templateUrl: 'view.html',
  controller: EmployeeDetailCtrl,
  bindings: {
    hello: '='
  }
});

function EmployeeDetailCtrl(){
  this.world = 'World!';
}
})(window.angular);
```

### HTML

```
<body ng-app="EmployeeInformation">
  <!-- components match only elements -->
<div ng-controller="EmployeeDetailCtrl as ctrl">
  <h1>
  <employee-detail hello="'Hello'"></employee-detail>
  </h1>
</div>
</body>
```

view.html

```
<span>{{$ctrl.hello}} {{$ctrl.world}}</span>
```

You need to specify an empty array after the module's name, even if you are not using any dependency on your app.

### Live example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8TbRcg5LBsdlqxLkUccJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error with the empty array added.

Comment: @medievalgeek I've made a plnkr example with a working code, and updated my question. Please, take a look now

Comment: Your update pointed me in the right direction.  I had to define the component object before I called `angular.component` on it.  I am updating my original post but will accept your answer since it helped me figure out the true problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: Being able to figure things by yourself, even after someone "hinted" you, that's way better than getting all the job done by someone else ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
(function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('EmployeeInformation', [])
    .controller('EmployeeDetailCtrl', EmployeeDetailCtrl)
    .component('employeeDetail', EmployeeDetail)
  ;

  var EmployeeDetail = {
    templateUrl: '../views/components/employeeDetail.html',
    controller: 'EmployeeDetailCtrl as empdetail',
    bindings: {
      employee: '<'
    }
  };

  function EmployeeDetailCtrl() { }
})(angular);
```